# WPA_Supplicant bgscan doesn't populate scan_results

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I'm using WPA_Supplicant 2.1 with Wext driver, on a custom Linux 2.6.27 kernel. The issue is that bgscan fails to populate 'scan_results' other than the network that wpa_supplicant is currently connected to. When I force a 'wpa_cli scan', 'scan_results' show 30 networks. Below are the logs, where I preform a manual scan via wpa_cli. It produces ~30 'scan_results' which you can then see fall off. After that, the bgscan shows only 1/32 networks in 'scan_results', which is the one that is currently connected to? One more weird thing is if I run 'iwlist mlan0 scan' the bgscan will populate with scan results?...

```
711895:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN'
712501:mlan0:Setting scan request:0
713206:mlan0:Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
713703:mlan0:Add radio work 'scan'@0x78b58
714174:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
714810:mlan0:Starting radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 after 0
065054:Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
073442:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
164184:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
166630:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
166926:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b19 len=8
167368:mlan0:Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
169442:Scan results did not fit - trying larger buffer (8192 bytes)
173282:Received 8143 bytes of scan results (29 BSSes)
174596:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 145
175115:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 125 BSSID c8:3a:35:cd:cb:f8 SSID 'brodrig'
177014:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
177558:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 126 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:96 SSID 'DaVinci'
179710:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
180262:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 127 BSSID 12:18:0a:10:0f:d5 SSID 'Meraki WPA2 Test'
182283:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
182825:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 128 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:95 SSID ''
187373:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
187922:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 129 BSSID 78:a5:04:24:f0:01 SSID 'renew-test'
190642:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
191200:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 130 BSSID 08:ea:44:7f:dc:16 SSID 'DaVinci'
193573:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
194121:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 131 BSSID 78:a5:04:26:99:5c SSID 'renew-max2'
196471:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
197024:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 132 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7b:96 SSID 'DaVinci'
199065:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
199613:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 133 BSSID 12:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki WPA2 Test'
201687:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
202234:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 134 BSSID bc:ee:7b:f1:81:30 SSID 'R2_TEST'
204643:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
205197:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 135 BSSID 16:18:0a:10:0f:d5 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test'
228330:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
233891:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 136 BSSID 00:27:22:4c:0b:38 SSID 'UBNT Bullet2'
237559:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
238109:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 137 BSSID 02:2d:5d:ef:19:66 SSID 'SYRUP'
240447:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
241404:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 138 BSSID 02:23:23:15:85:11 SSID 'Service (5317521032)'
243134:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
243924:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 139 BSSID 16:18:0a:03:0c:46 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test'
245687:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
291237:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 140 BSSID 16:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test'
300578:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
305609:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 141 BSSID 1c:99:4c:d2:fb:ff SSID 'GNSS 0080'
312080:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
314801:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 142 BSSID 1c:99:4c:d2:98:75 SSID 'GNSS 0008'
316496:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
329554:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 143 BSSID 02:24:34:cd:66:c6 SSID 'Service (5135561306)'
330145:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
330649:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 144 BSSID 02:27:b7:b7:b9:54 SSID 'Service (5046589188)'
331208:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
331698:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 145 BSSID 02:2d:ad:a9:a5:a2 SSID 'Service (5051593080)'
332998:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
333513:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 146 BSSID 02:24:a4:8d:ed:87 SSID 'Service (5132555740)'
334077:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
334578:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 147 BSSID 08:ea:44:7f:dc:14 SSID 'Guest Network'
335206:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
335712:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 148 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:94 SSID 'Guest Network'
393377:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
401193:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 149 BSSID 00:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki Open Test'
447658:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
452518:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 150 BSSID 40:f3:08:a6:fc:55 SSID 'GNSS 0879'
458998:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
459567:mlan0:BSS:Add new id 151 BSSID 04:46:65:d0:14:d5 SSID '1028014797'
465164:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
465585:BSS:last_scan_res_used=29/32
517742:mlan0:New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
519668:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
520654:bgscan simple:scan result notification
521539:mlan0:Radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 done in 2
522035:mlan0:Selecting BSS from priority group 99
522685:mlan0:0:c8:3a:35:cd:cb:f8 ssid='brodrig' wpa_ie_len=22 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-53
523225:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
524270:mlan0:1:08:ea:44:98:7c:96 ssid='DaVinci' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=26 caps=0x11 level=-43
524736:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
525387:mlan0:2:12:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki WPA2 Test' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-58
606133:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
608329:mlan0:3:08:ea:44:98:7c:95 ssid='' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=26 caps=0x11 level=-43
608857:mlan0:skip - SSID not known
609512:mlan0:4:78:a5:04:24:f0:01 ssid='renew-test' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-52
611296:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
611972:mlan0:5:08:ea:44:7f:dc:16 ssid='DaVinci' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=26 caps=0x11 level=-61
614375:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
615724:mlan0:6:78:a5:04:26:99:5c ssid='renew-max2' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-59
674095:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
719883:mlan0:7:08:ea:44:98:7b:96 ssid='DaVinci' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=26 caps=0x11 level=-74
744880:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
804611:mlan0:8:12:18:0a:10:12:76 ssid='Meraki WPA2 Test' wpa_ie_len=26 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x11 level=-81
809857:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
814586:mlan0:9:bc:ee:7b:f1:81:30 ssid='R2_TEST' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x11 level=-83 wps
831179:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
856200:mlan0:10:16:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki WEP Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-54
861962:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
894035:mlan0:11:00:27:22:4c:0b:38 ssid='UBNT Bullet2' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-47
902895:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
906394:mlan0:12:02:2d:5d:ef:19:66 ssid='SYRUP' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-63
906796:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
907346:mlan0:13:02:23:23:15:85:11 ssid='Service (5317521032)' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-69
907829:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
908382:mlan0:14:16:18:0a:03:0c:46 ssid='Meraki WEP Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-74
908769:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
909309:mlan0:15:16:18:0a:10:12:76 ssid='Meraki WEP Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-79
909863:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
910413:mlan0:16:1c:99:4c:d2:fb:ff ssid='GNSS 0080' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-83
910801:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
911385:mlan0:17:1c:99:4c:d2:98:75 ssid='GNSS 0008' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x11 level=-83
911787:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
912340:mlan0:18:02:24:34:cd:66:c6 ssid='Service (5135561306)' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-87
912728:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
913277:mlan0:19:02:27:b7:b7:b9:54 ssid='Service (5046589188)' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-88
917478:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
918047:mlan0:20:02:2d:ad:a9:a5:a2 ssid='Service (5051593080)' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-89
918439:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
919046:mlan0:21:02:24:a4:8d:ed:87 ssid='Service (5132555740)' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x12 level=-91
919443:mlan0:skip - SSID mismatch
919991:mlan0:22:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x1 level=-59
920381:mlan0:allow in non-WPA/WPA2
920845:mlan0:selected BSS 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test'
922042:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
630644:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
769811:mlan0:Control interface command 'STATUS-VERBOSE'
526001:bgscan simple:Request a background scan
526560:mlan0:Add radio work 'scan'@0x78b58
526971:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
527508:mlan0:Starting radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 after 0
779351:Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
817552:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
818169:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
818781:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
819077:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b19 len=8
819527:mlan0:Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
820271:Received 578 bytes of scan results (2 BSSes)
820788:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 146
821208:BSS:last_scan_res_used=2/32
821684:mlan0:New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
823817:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
824550:bgscan simple:scan result notification
824958:mlan0:Radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 done in 1
825371:mlan0:Selecting BSS from priority group 99
856134:mlan0:0:00:18:0a:03:0c:46 ssid='Meraki Open Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x1 level=-72
863835:mlan0:allow in non-WPA/WPA2
889285:mlan0:selected BSS 00:18:0a:03:0c:46 ssid='Meraki Open Test'
894528:mlan0:Considering connect request:reassociate:0  selected:00:18:0a:03:0c:46  bssid:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5  pending:00:00:00:00:00:00  wpa_state:COMPLETED  ssid=0x6ea40  current_ssid=0x6ea40
896391:mlan0:Request association with 00:18:0a:03:0c:46
896818:mlan0:Add radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48
897218:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
897831:mlan0:Starting radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48 after 0
898346:mlan0:Trying to associate with 00:18:0a:03:0c:46 (SSID='Meraki Open Test' freq=2462 MHz)
900614:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
901578:mlan0:Cancelling scan request
902069:mlan0:WPA:clearing own WPA/RSN IE
902464:mlan0:Automatic auth_alg selection:0x1
902849:mlan0:WPA:clearing AP WPA IE
904016:mlan0:WPA:clearing AP RSN IE
904432:mlan0:WPA:clearing own WPA/RSN IE
904874:mlan0:State:COMPLETED -> ASSOCIATING
905225:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 1->0 (DORMANT)
929452:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
950330:bgscan:Deinitializing module 'simple'
951283:Limit connection to BSSID 00:18:0a:03:0c:46 freq=2462 MHz based on scan results (bssid_set=0)
955426:wpa_driver_wext_associate
955692:wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
977287:wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
253043:mlan0:Setting authentication timeout:10 sec 0 usec
258569:EAPOL:External notification - EAP success=0
263088:EAPOL:External notification - EAP fail=0
288046:EAPOL:External notification - portControl=ForceAuthorized
293296:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
338590:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
348147:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
356181:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
357987:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
358966:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
359564:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
359852:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b06 len=8
360260:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
360800:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
361375:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
361664:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b04 len=12
362140:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
362681:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
363247:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
363536:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b15 len=20
363893:Wireless event:new AP:00:18:0a:03:0c:46
364682:mlan0:Event ASSOC (0) received
365127:mlan0:State:ASSOCIATING -> ASSOCIATED
365482:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
411275:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
416571:mlan0:Associated to a new BSS:BSSID=00:18:0a:03:0c:46
417337:mlan0:Associated with 00:18:0a:03:0c:46
417795:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
419773:mlan0:WPA:Association event - clear replay counter
420153:mlan0:WPA:Clear old PTK
420499:EAPOL:External notification - portEnabled=0
420795:EAPOL:SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
421039:EAPOL:Supplicant port status:Unauthorized
421329:EAPOL:SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
422272:EAPOL:External notification - portValid=0
422589:EAPOL:External notification - portEnabled=1
422882:EAPOL:SUPP_PAE entering state S_FORCE_AUTH
423123:EAPOL:Supplicant port status:Authorized
423413:EAPOL:SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
423710:mlan0:Cancelling authentication timeout
425217:mlan0:State:ASSOCIATED -> COMPLETED
425697:mlan0:Radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48 done in 1
462000:mlan0:CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:18:0a:03:0c:46 completed [id=0 id_str=]
466200:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
466541:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 0->1 (UP)
467046:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
468927:bgscan simple:Signal strength threshold -60  Short bgscan interval 5  Long bgscan interval 30
469940:bgscan simple:Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
470199:bgscan simple:Init scan interval:5
470514:bgscan:Initialized module 'simple' with parameters '5:-60:30'
471159:Received 305 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
471661:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 147
472045:bgscan simple:scan result notification
472376:mlan0:Cancelling scan request
472780:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
473697:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
474303:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
475982:bgscan simple:Request a background scan
510500:mlan0:Add radio work 'scan'@0x78b58
510959:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
511496:mlan0:Starting radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 after 0
763769:Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
774331:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
775118:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
785521:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
793611:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b19 len=8
800026:mlan0:Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
808571:Received 578 bytes of scan results (2 BSSes)
819420:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 148
820028:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 125 BSSID c8:3a:35:cd:cb:f8 SSID 'brodrig' due to no match in scan
822219:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
823303:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 126 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:96 SSID 'DaVinci' due to no match in scan
825292:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
826425:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 127 BSSID 12:18:0a:10:0f:d5 SSID 'Meraki WPA2 Test' due to no match in scan
831476:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
832016:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 128 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:95 SSID '' due to no match in scan
833892:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
834437:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 129 BSSID 78:a5:04:24:f0:01 SSID 'renew-test' due to no match in scan
836633:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
837176:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 130 BSSID 08:ea:44:7f:dc:16 SSID 'DaVinci' due to no match in scan
838354:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
838876:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 131 BSSID 78:a5:04:26:99:5c SSID 'renew-max2' due to no match in scan
839442:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
839933:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 132 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7b:96 SSID 'DaVinci' due to no match in scan
840549:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
841048:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 133 BSSID 12:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki WPA2 Test' due to no match in scan
841604:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
842092:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 134 BSSID bc:ee:7b:f1:81:30 SSID 'R2_TEST' due to no match in scan
842647:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
843131:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 135 BSSID 16:18:0a:10:0f:d5 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test' due to no match in scan
843687:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
845690:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 136 BSSID 00:27:22:4c:0b:38 SSID 'UBNT Bullet2' due to no match in scan
850512:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
857628:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 137 BSSID 02:2d:5d:ef:19:66 SSID 'SYRUP' due to no match in scan
858872:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
859383:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 138 BSSID 02:23:23:15:85:11 SSID 'Service (5317521032)' due to no match in scan
859948:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
860438:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 139 BSSID 16:18:0a:03:0c:46 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test' due to no match in scan
860989:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
861476:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 140 BSSID 16:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki WEP Test' due to no match in scan
862030:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
862515:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 141 BSSID 1c:99:4c:d2:fb:ff SSID 'GNSS 0080' due to no match in scan
863065:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
864005:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 142 BSSID 1c:99:4c:d2:98:75 SSID 'GNSS 0008' due to no match in scan
865471:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
867793:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 143 BSSID 02:24:34:cd:66:c6 SSID 'Service (5135561306)' due to no match in scan
872979:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
879827:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 144 BSSID 02:27:b7:b7:b9:54 SSID 'Service (5046589188)' due to no match in scan
886787:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
888675:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 145 BSSID 02:2d:ad:a9:a5:a2 SSID 'Service (5051593080)' due to no match in scan
889268:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
889766:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 146 BSSID 02:24:a4:8d:ed:87 SSID 'Service (5132555740)' due to no match in scan
890326:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
890815:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 147 BSSID 08:ea:44:7f:dc:14 SSID 'Guest Network' due to no match in scan
891458:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
891943:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 148 BSSID 08:ea:44:98:7c:94 SSID 'Guest Network' due to no match in scan
892499:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
892981:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 150 BSSID 40:f3:08:a6:fc:55 SSID 'GNSS 0879' due to no match in scan
893541:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
894026:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 151 BSSID 04:46:65:d0:14:d5 SSID '1028014797' due to no match in scan
894999:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
895370:BSS:last_scan_res_used=2/32
903497:mlan0:New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
905929:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
906292:bgscan simple:scan result notification
908024:mlan0:Radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 done in 1
910252:mlan0:Selecting BSS from priority group 99
910816:mlan0:0:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x1 level=-54
912687:mlan0:allow in non-WPA/WPA2
914836:mlan0:selected BSS 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test'
915245:mlan0:Considering within-ESS reassociation
917175:mlan0:Current BSS:00:18:0a:03:0c:46 level=-74
917644:mlan0:Selected BSS:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 level=-54
930019:mlan0:Considering connect request:reassociate:0  selected:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5  bssid:00:18:0a:03:0c:46  pending:00:00:00:00:00:00  wpa_state:COMPLETED  ssid=0x6ea40  current_ssid=0x6ea40
930561:mlan0:Request association with 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5
930991:mlan0:Add radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48
931383:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
931965:mlan0:Starting radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48 after 0
932479:mlan0:Trying to associate with 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 (SSID='Meraki Open Test' freq=2412 MHz)
932931:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
933313:mlan0:Cancelling scan request
933696:mlan0:WPA:clearing own WPA/RSN IE
934086:mlan0:Automatic auth_alg selection:0x1
934469:mlan0:WPA:clearing AP WPA IE
934842:mlan0:WPA:clearing AP RSN IE
935215:mlan0:WPA:clearing own WPA/RSN IE
935623:mlan0:State:COMPLETED -> ASSOCIATING
937802:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 1->0 (DORMANT)
939924:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
943937:bgscan:Deinitializing module 'simple'
944348:Limit connection to BSSID 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 freq=2412 MHz based on scan results (bssid_set=0)
946822:wpa_driver_wext_associate
947137:wpa_driver_wext_set_drop_unencrypted
951520:wpa_driver_wext_set_psk
257047:mlan0:Setting authentication timeout:10 sec 0 usec
265727:EAPOL:External notification - EAP success=0
296736:EAPOL:External notification - EAP fail=0
308368:EAPOL:External notification - portControl=ForceAuthorized
317579:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
330863:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
381928:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
448649:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
460784:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
478494:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
478816:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b06 len=8
479223:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
479844:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
482067:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
482366:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b04 len=12
484106:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
484672:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
486657:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
486983:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b15 len=20
487352:Wireless event:new AP:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5
489520:mlan0:Event ASSOC (0) received
490288:mlan0:State:ASSOCIATING -> ASSOCIATED
491993:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
492514:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
494520:mlan0:Associated to a new BSS:BSSID=00:18:0a:10:0f:d5
495024:mlan0:Associated with 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5
498426:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
499911:mlan0:WPA:Association event - clear replay counter
500309:mlan0:WPA:Clear old PTK
502186:EAPOL:External notification - portEnabled=0
502560:EAPOL:SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
502805:EAPOL:Supplicant port status:Unauthorized
503098:EAPOL:SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
504047:EAPOL:External notification - portValid=0
505065:EAPOL:External notification - portEnabled=1
505372:EAPOL:SUPP_PAE entering state S_FORCE_AUTH
505614:EAPOL:Supplicant port status:Authorized
576632:EAPOL:SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
576994:mlan0:Cancelling authentication timeout
577483:mlan0:State:ASSOCIATED -> COMPLETED
578026:mlan0:Radio work 'connect'@0x6dd48 done in 1
578580:mlan0:CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 completed [id=0 id_str=]
588581:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
589088:wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate:operstate 0->1 (UP)
589693:netlink:Operstate:ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
591675:bgscan simple:Signal strength threshold -60  Short bgscan interval 5  Long bgscan interval 30
592383:bgscan simple:Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
592673:bgscan simple:Init scan interval:5
593055:bgscan:Initialized module 'simple' with parameters '5:-60:30'
593938:Received 578 bytes of scan results (2 BSSes)
594540:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 149
595001:bgscan simple:scan result notification
595405:mlan0:Cancelling scan request
648455:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
665042:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
668853:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
669813:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
690264:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
598515:bgscan simple:Request a background scan
603768:mlan0:Add radio work 'scan'@0x78b58
612257:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
621138:mlan0:Starting radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 after 0
884322:Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
886626:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
887308:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
887942:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
888234:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b19 len=8
888764:mlan0:Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
889366:Received 273 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
889869:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 150
890400:mlan0:BSS:Remove id 149 BSSID 00:18:0a:10:12:76 SSID 'Meraki Open Test' due to no match in scan
891084:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
891556:BSS:last_scan_res_used=1/32
892023:mlan0:New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
892580:CTRL_IFACE monitor sent successfully to /tmp/wpa_ctrl_iface_1805\x00
892913:bgscan simple:scan result notification
893308:mlan0:Radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 done in 1
893714:mlan0:Selecting BSS from priority group 99
894257:mlan0:0:00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=0 caps=0x1 level=-54
894657:mlan0:allow in non-WPA/WPA2
895125:mlan0:selected BSS 00:18:0a:10:0f:d5 ssid='Meraki Open Test'
904051:mlan0:Control interface command 'SCAN_RESULTS'
895967:bgscan simple:Request a background scan
896418:mlan0:Add radio work 'scan'@0x78b58
896813:mlan0:First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
897339:mlan0:Starting radio work 'scan'@0x78b58 after 0
143177:Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
149955:RTM_NEWLINK:operstate=1 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
150543:RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME:Interface 'mlan0' added
151133:WEXT:if_removed already cleared - ignore event
151419:Wireless event:cmd=0x8b19 len=8
151858:mlan0:Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
152460:Received 305 bytes of scan results (1 BSSes)
152961:mlan0:BSS:Start scan result update 151
153338:BSS:last_scan_res_used=1/32
```

Any idea's on what might be going on here, maybe I misunderstand how bgscan is suppose to work or I have a configuration wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"The goal of bgscan is to find roaming
candidates within the same ESS, so while it may not be by design, not
updating results for other networks would be proper behavior." -Jouni Malinen

Source:http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2015-May/032898.html